# Get value of checkbox of Form1 from Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I've looked around here and on some other sites relating to this, and have found answers. However, either the solution does not work or is just too obscure for me to understand. I'll explain what I mean when I say it "wont work".

There are two ways that I have tried to do this. The first one using `get` and `set`, and the second, simply setting the control modifier to true.

When using either of those, it seems like the value in `Form1`'s designer doesn't update, and so `Form2` only reads the value as being false, since that is the value of the checkbox by default.

In `Form1`:

```
    public bool CheckBox
    {
        get { return this.checkBox1.Checked; }
        //set { this.checkBox1.Checked = value; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();

        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

In `Form2`:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();

        if (frm.CheckBox == true)
        {
            //Do whatever
        }
    }
```

That's basically all I'm trying to do. If I am doing something wrong, or if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You need a reference to the form, not a new one.

Comment: I'm still pretty much a beginner with C#, I wasn't aware of any of this. Thank you, to everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `Form` instance in `Form2`.It's a completely different instance from your current `Form1` instance.

Instead you can pass your current Form1 instance to `ShowDialog` method like this:

```
 frm.ShowDialog(this);
```

By doing this you are setting  [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `Form2` to your `Form1` instance.Therefore you can access your current instance with `Owner` property from `Form2`. Also you should cast it to `Form1` to access `CheckBox` property.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (((Form1)Owner).CheckBox == true)
    {
        //Do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am *guessing* that the issue here is how you are using instance variables. Say I have two forms - Form1 and Form2 and they are defined as follows:

```
Form1 a = new Form1();
Form2 b = new Form2();
```

Now later in the life cycle of the application the user clicks a button *on form 2*, what you have is (pseudocode):

```
// ... somewhere in "Form2" ...
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Form1 c = new Form1();
   c.Checkbox = true;
}
```

The problem is that "c" is not the same as "a" Form1 - they are two different instances of the same form. The simplest way to solve this problem is to make your checkbox static:

```
// in Form1...
public static bool CheckBox { get; set; }
```

Now you only have one checkbox value and it is the same for all "copies" (instances) of Form1.

**Notes**

This works, *but* it isn't perfect. If you want two copies of Form1 and you wan't each to have its own value for "CheckBox" this isn't going to work for you. Instead what you need to do is start to pass instances around. So, the code I listed at the beginning of my answer needs to change to be something like:

```
Form1 a = new Form1();
Form2 b = new Form2(a);
```

Where "Form2" is now defined as:

```
public class Form2 : System.Windows.Forms.Form {
   private Form1 copyOfForm1;

   public Form2(Form1 theInstance) {
     InitializeComponent();
     copyOfForm1 = theInstance;
   }
}
```

Now anywhere you want to access that one *instance* of Form1 from inside of FormB, you can do it just by using the "copyOfForm1" variable. This is **FAR** from everything there is to say about instance/static, but hopefully it at least gets you going on the right track. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

On Form2, make your checkbox value a property. When you close the form, you can set the DialogResult to OK. So on form2's close event or wherever you want really:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Then use the following to create, show, and retrieve the checkbox value (will also dispose of form2 when it's closed). When DialogResult is OK, you can get the value from the property.

```
using (var form2 = new Form2())
{
    if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var checkboxValue = form2.Checkbox;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to close the form, you can set another bool property to true and check that property whenever you want to get the value of the checkbox. So in form2:

```
public bool CheckboxSelected { get; set; }
public bool Checkbox { get; set; }
event for Checkbox change:
    Checkbox = value of checkbox;
    CheckboxSelected = true;
```

And then on Form1 you can watch for CheckboxSelected == true:

```
using (var form2 = new Form2())
{
    if (form2.CheckboxSelected == true)
    {
        var checkboxValue = form2.Checkbox;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A someone easier solution:

Form1:

(Code that runs when checkbox is checked)

```
if(CheckBox1.Checked == true)
{
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Checked.txt", "true");
}
```

Form2:

(Code that runs when form is loaded)

```
string GetResult = File.ReadLines("C:\\Checked.txt").First();

if(GetResult == "true")
{
///Any Code Here///
}
```